# Server side handling of duplicate POST requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-mvc-5, duplicates

**TL;DR: I want to implement this behavior:**

1. **I decorate a specific POST action in a controller with a custom
   attribute, which only specifies a custom int parameter, in seconds,
   like [PreventSpam(Seconds=10)] => two requests from the same client
   are considered "duplicate" if the POST object is identical and the
   timespan between the two is less than "Seconds"**
2. **When processing a request, if it's detected as "Duplicate"
   (according to previous definition) it shouldn't be processed.
   Instead, the ActionResult (whatever it is, a view, a JSON..) of the
   previous, non-duplicate request should be returned. Of course that
   implies that the ActionResult should have been cached by the first
   request.**

**If I'm able to implement this, I would never have to worry again about the user performing multiple clicks when submitting a request, hence duplicating the request, instead of having to manually handle this through javascript.**

I'm experiencing the following problem with MVC 5: when an user rapidly clicks the submit button of a form, multiple, identical POST requests are generated.

For the sake of security, we would like to handle this problem server-side *(nobody could prevent a malicious user to submit multiple request if I only disable the submit button through javascript..)*

I want to achieve the following result: when multiple, identical requested are detected on a specific action (let's say, the timespan between them is less than 10 secs) only the first request is considered -> **ALL THE FOLLOWING REQUESTS SHOULD POINT EXACTLY TO THE SAME "ActionResult" GENERATED BY THE FIRST REQUEST, WHICH SHOULD SOMEHOW BE CACHED, SO THAT THE ACTION IS ACTUALLY EXECUTED ONLY ONCE**

Taking inspiration from this guide (http://rion.io/2013/02/24/prevent-repeated-requests-using-actionfilters-in-asp-net-mvc/), which achieves something similar (if multiple requests are detected a modelstate error is added..), I've come up with this code:

```
public class PreventSpamAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    //This stores the time between Requests (in seconds)
    public int DelayRequest = 10;

    //THIS IS CALLED *AFTER* THE FIRST ACTION HAS BEEN PROPERLY EXECUTED -> THE ACTIONRESULT OBJECT HAS BEEN DETERMINED
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Cache;

        //I CACHE THE ACTION RESULT FOR "DelayRequest" SECONDS, USING THE GENERATED HASH AS KEY
        cache.Add(_getHash(filterContext.HttpContext), filterContext.Result, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(DelayRequest), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default, null);

        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }

    //THIS IS CALLED *BEFORE* CALLING THE ACTION
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Cache;

        var hash = _getHash(filterContext.HttpContext);

        //IF I ALREADY HAVE A CACHED RESULT IT MEANS THAT THE USER CLICKED MULTIPLE TIMES,
        //INSTEAD OF CALLING THE ACTION I SIMPLY RETURN THE ACTIONRESULT THAT I CACHED..
        if (cache[hash] != null)            
            filterContext.Result = (ActionResult)cache[hash];

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    //GENERATES UNIQUE HASH, CONSIDERING VARIOUS REQUEST PARAMETERS
    private string _getHash(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //Store our HttpContext (for easier reference and code brevity)
        var request = httpContext.Request;
        //Store our HttpContext.Cache (for easier reference and code brevity)
        var cache = httpContext.Cache;

        //Grab the IP Address from the originating Request (very simple implementation for example purposes)
        var originationInfo = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? request.UserHostAddress;

        //Append the User Agent
        originationInfo += request.UserAgent;

        //Now we just need the target URL Information
        var targetInfo = request.RawUrl + request.QueryString;

        //Generate a hash for your strings (this appends each of the bytes of the value into a single hashed string
        return string.Join("", MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(originationInfo + targetInfo)).Select(s => s.ToString("x2")));
    }
}
```

**Unfortunately I feel there's a major issue with this approach: what if this action takes some time to generate the ActionResult?** When the duplicate request reaches the server, a different thread may still be working on the first one, so that the ActionResult hasn't been cached yet. So the request is processed again..even if the action itself is synchronous, as of my understanding if there are multiple simultaneous requests to the same action, different threads from the threadpool will be assigned the different requests, so that they could be executed simultaneously. Is this correct?

**MY FINAL GOAL:
handling everything server-side, even if the user presses the submit button in a form multiple times, nothing different than pressing it a single time should happen**

**UPDATE 07/09/2016:**
Storing a token in an hidden field of each form isn't really practical in this scenario: in several of our views, we're manually calling post actions through javascript, in this fashion:

```
myUrl = '@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")';

myPostObject = {
   entityId: 15,
   someValue: "aValue",
}

$.post(myUrl, myPostObject, callbackFunction);
```

Having to manually edit each "myPostObject" to contain an extra GUID field would be very time consuming and error-prone. That's the reason why we're looking for a solution which is completely server side and that requires only to decorate the relevant actions with a custom attribute.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: You're right of course. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest there is a major flaw in the concept here - if your site is behind a Network Load Balancer, there is no way any MVC code can tell that it has already received the same request on another server, or IIS instance.

IIS will happily spin up another thread (in WebGarden mode) if its under load, so your single application instance can never reliably tell if the user is using a duplicate post attack.

Eventually your code will call out to a shaded state server somewhere (a database, typically, but could be a shared memory cache) and that is when you can tell whether the user has already submitted the request.

Comment: Ok, but what if I acquire a lock on an object that exists in the context of a single session: acquire the lock on OnActionExecuting(..) and release the lock OnResultExecuted(..). Wouldn't that force each duplicate request to wait till the first request has properly cached the ActionResult, while still being able to process different requests (belonging to different sessions) at the same time (because in this case the locked objects would be different..)?

Comment: What this is likely to do it force IIS to spin up another instance, since it believes the previous call is still being processed. 

If you want a very lightweight and not-at-all foolproof method of preventing multi-click-reposts just add a hidden Guid to the page, when you get the POST check to see if it exists in the cache - if it doesn't, then add it. If it does, you know its a second post.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood what you mean. My thought: considering the same client, when the first request is received, the lock on a session object is acquired and the action is executed. If a second request is received from the same client before the first one is fully processed, this second request will block before the locking statement. When the first request is fully processed (and so the actionResult is stored in the cache) the lock is released. The second request can now acquire the lock. It detects that there's a cached ActionResult, which is immediately returned. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You are assuming that the second request will be routed to the same IIS server, the same IIS instance on that server. When in Web Garden mode IIS will spawn a new w3wp.exe process when a given call length is reached. Blocking a call is a good way to trigger IIS into creating a new Process and bypassing your internal process locking. In a round-robin NLB scenario, the second call from the same client will be deliberately routed to a completely different server anyway, again bypassing your ASP.net locking. So your design will work if all of those scenarios don't exist.

Comment: The application will run on a single server which is not configured to work in a Web Garden. Still, I'm having problems acquiring / releasing the lock I was talking about since I would have to acquire it in a method and release it in a different method. I don't know if such a thing is possible. Considering the update that you can find in the main topic (UPDATE 07/09/2016) which explains why using a guid would be impractical, do you think that it's possible to achieve the desired result completely server-side? Thanks

Comment: Yes - if you look at the Mutex class this enables the acquisition and releasing of a cross process lock object, by name rather than by object reference.This is often used to prevent multiple copies of the same winforms application being loaded (a Named Mutex is obtained by the first to be loaded and subsequent load attempts check to see if the Named Mutex is available). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf(v=vs.110).aspx gives examples of named mutex across processes.